# Topological number and gauge invariance

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, gauge-invariance, instantons

In QCD or other non-abelian gauge theories, we come across infinitely many vacua that are gauge equivalent but have different topological numbers. We then say that the instanton solution is tunnelling solution between these vacua.

But when we learn about gauge invariance, we are told that gauge equivalent vacua are physically the same state. So how is it possible to have tunnelling between states that are physically the same?

Or if the topological number makes these vacua distinct, what is the physical meaning of the topological number?